# Problems with my boss in academia: who to ask for some advice in Austria?

Tags: ethics, postdocs, authorship, conflict-of-interest, projects

I have some problems with my boss at a university.
The problem does not only include cooperative aspects. It also involves some problems related to a post-doc project that I developed and that I gave to my boss (current principal investigator) who proposed to expand the project and provide funding for PhD research. The project is now in his name on the promise that he would let me lead the project.

Now, my post-doc project has been removed, and my boss started to develop the project as he wants without coming to any agreements with me at all, because he is the principal investigator.

Now, the question: in such a weird situation, who can I ask for advice in Austria? I asked the head of research, and he told me to talk with my boss (and I did). I don't know how to deal with this situation, I feel like people don't really want to discuss this issue and I may ruin some relations with other colleagues as they may feel awkward to get involved. On top, I am on the weak side: I can either resign or follow his directions without complaining. I cannot work on my initial project proposal, and I am not author anymore of the proposal.

Comment: Are you in need of this project to fund your position?

Comment: Hi @Snijderfrey, I guess I couldn't fully understand the question. I would say that this project was the topic I wanted to work on. There was more information on a previous explanation of mine, but since I was asked to focus the subject, I provided only the basic information useful to build a repository. Basically, there is a broken: on the promise to let me work on my project, after 2 months since the beginning and only congratulations on the quick progresses, my boss suddenly changed the project on his whim, without caring of my original proposal.